# WebView Content Security Policy

Tags: android, webview, vimeo

I want to load a video from Vimeo in a WebView. It works, but the preview image doesn't load and I get this error:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/-5228946977756841864' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https://i.vimeocdn.com https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com https://f.vimeocdn.com https://vimeo.com https://sb.scorecardresearch.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://secure.gravatar.com https://i0.wp.com https://i1.wp.com https://i2.wp.com".
>                                                                    ", source: https://player.vimeo.com/video/172374044 (0)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am using webview_flutter_plus package in Flutter and I am getting the same issue. I tried adding this <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; img-src * data: blob: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
but no luck.

Answer (score 12):

Add the following to `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag `img-src` directive:

```
android-webview-video-poster:
```

As in:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; img-src * data: blob: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Comment: Did you notice that the video was sized incorrectly when you were seeing the error, before you added the meta tag fix? I'm getting the same error and the video itself is not sized properly to fit the android web view.

Comment: Where to add that I am not JS guy, please help.

Comment: Add that inside the `<head>` tag in the HTML page

Comment: @cavalleydude I would like to not permit this to * (evryone) but 'self' is not working, see the error Refused to load the image 'android-webview:default_video_poster/4145483716572850442' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: android-webview-video-poster:".

Comment: Any idea about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470420/flutter-web-view-secure-origin

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `poster` attribute to your `<video>` tag. An empty image works. The default `android-webview-video-poster` looks awful anyway.