# Vimeo video in fullscreen landscape webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fullscreen, vimeo-android

I'm trying to correctly display a Vimeo video in a fullscreen landscape activity.
The video has "strange" white margin on top and bottom.

[image]

These are the webview settings:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I inject with:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://vimeo.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src * gap:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; img-src * data: blob: android-webview-video-poster:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/445319847" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
        width="100%" height="100%" margin="0" padding="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" ,
        frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

I added the meta content, reading this console log:

*"Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/5386880230549634306' because it violates
the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https://i.vimeocdn.com
https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com https://f.vimeocdn.com https://vimeo.com https://secure.gravatar.com https://i0.wp.com
https://i1.wp.com https://i2.wp.com https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com https://player.vimeo.com
https://*.ci.vimeows.com https://f.vimeocdn.com".", source: https://player.vimeo.com/video/445319847 (0)*

And then landing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40412110/2373113). BTW the warning is not disappearing and the fix seems not to work. Any ideas? Many thanks.

EDIT: if it's not possible to have the player exactly fullscreen, how can I fullfill the white space with e.g. black?

Comment: How did you fix the issue? I am getting the same warning  "Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/-3248712023037699476' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data

Comment: I've not fixed it, I'm living with the warning...

Comment: So is your app live on play store? Won't there be any issue if you still have the warning? Will not play store have any problem with this? As I see this is Security Policy issue I was wondering if we can really ignore this warning.

Comment: Today I'll try a native approach via API and PRO Vimeo account.

Comment: Do let me know how it worked for you and if it still gave you the same warning.

Comment: I've gave up on using webview as it's not officially supported by Vimeo. I've setup Exoplayer + vimeo-networking-java embedding an access token to play my own videos.

Answer (score 2):

nothing strange in here. `iframe` is fulfiling your `WebView` (`width="100%" height="100%"` no html margins, padding etc.), which is drawn at size of screen. Whole screen, also below status bar, thus not equal white margins (I bet you are using `fitsSystemWindows` attr)

`iframe` is loading webpage `src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/445319847"` and this page contains player which is trying to fulfil frame (in this case fit width), but keeps aspect ratio and center player itself

Fix: make some native player (recomending [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)) and load direct video file link into, some example how to extract mp4 link in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042573/get-direct-vimeo-video-url-android)

Comment: is it possible to fullfill the white with black?

Comment: you may try to add some background to your HTML code or use `webview.setBackgroundColor`, but this white background may be also determined by code loaded into `iframe` (`src` link)